# Copy, Insert big amount of rows into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to copy over 1 Million rows from one table to an other. Because we have over 50 database to update I use a small php program to initiate the transaction per database. But while i am just testing on one database i notice that if i use a "Insert into Select from" statement the server only copy around 10000 lines and then suddenly stops?

We are doing an overhaul of a database and we created a transaction with several update and insert querys to do the job, all other querys in the transaction are finished. but the bulk insert not??? Even that after the bulk insert are still some other tsql actions??

I use following tsql script as part of a transaction:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_SystemStatistics] ( 40 column)  
SELECT 40 column 
FROM [dbo].[tbl_SystemStatisticsOverhaul]
```

Comment: How do you know it stopped at 10,000?

Comment: Sounds like you need to break up your queries.

Comment: I know its around 10000 records as i can see in the table where i move to.

Comment: How can i split up a insert into???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
      @x INT
    , @count INT

SELECT 
      @count = COUNT(1)
    , @x = 1 
FROM dbo.tbl_SystemStatisticsOverhaul

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
    WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#import')
) DROP TABLE #import;

SELECT [column], RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)
INTO #import
FROM dbo.tbl_SystemStatisticsOverhaul

WHILE @x < @count BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_SystemStatistics ([column])  
    SELECT [column]
    FROM #import 
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @x AND @x + 9

    SELECT @x = @x + 10

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your max_execution_time in php reach? Default is 30sec I think. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: i have extended the execution time to 500 already. I think there must be some limitation in SQL! I mean the complete transation is executed. and we have around 20 different statements here. Only the insert from that table is not completed :s